# por que no reconoce certificado ssl?

Tags: web, cloud

instale un certificado SSL de CloudFlare, resulta que estaba andando bien, y de la nada dejo de funcionar, en la pagina ahora aparece "Su sitio web no posee certificado SSL" y en la cabecera muestra el protocolo https como no seguro, alguien sabe a que se debe?

[ESTA ES LA PAGINA](https://saltapersonalizados.com/)

Comment: Yo lo veo bien, quizás sea se deba al cache de tu navegador. Intenta cambiar a navegador o visitar la pagina desde una pestaña de incógnito.

Comment: sabes que desde la empresa del hosting tambien me dijeron lo mismo, intente borrar cache, hasta desinstale el navegador, borre con ccleaner los registros, y volví a instalar, pero me sigue apareciendo igual a mi, a que se debera?

Comment: Al revisar la pagina se ve como segura en este momento, normalmente cuando ocurre este tipo de cosas con los certificados ssl de cloudflare, tienes que dejar de usar los ssl full de ellos y colocar el flexible, adicional usar las reglas de cloudflare para que todos los elementos sean clasificados como seguros. usa esta regla `http://*tusitio.com/*` always use https

Comment: A mi me sale bien...

Comment: A mi tambien me sale bien, espera unas horas y seguro ya lo tendrás sin problema

Comment: si, resulto ser el cache, en la web de cloud se puede habilitar el modo developer para evitar el cache